# Keep the mouse active after disconnecting from remote desktop

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, mouse, java

I'm running a Java program that uses the auto mouse clicker to function.

It works fine when the remote desktop client is opened on my screen but as soon as I minimize it or close the remote connection, the Java code runs but the auto mouse clicker stops working.

Is there a way to make sure that the mouse works even after closing the remote desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you run the program directly at your machine. If you can run it at the remote machine, that should solve the problem.